# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Делаю слайдер и у меня возникла ошибка. Во-первых он не работает, во-вторых одна из кнопок не работает. Появляется ошибка "Сannot read property 'style' of undefined"
Код:

```
var slide = document.getElementById('slider_ul');
var slides = slide.getElementsByTagName('li');  
var currentSlide = 0;


function leftBtn() {
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'none';
   currentSlide = (++currentSlide)%slides.length;
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'block';
}

function rightBtn() {
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'none';
   currentSlide = (--currentSlide)%slides.length;
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Ошибка возникает именно на функции rightBtn. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему не работает:

```js
var a = -1;
var b = 3;
console.log(a, "%", b, "=", a % b);
```

Как правильно:

```js
var slide = document.getElementById('slider_ul');
var slides = slide.querySelectorAll('li');  
var currentSlide = 0;

function leftBtn() {
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'none';
   currentSlide = (++currentSlide) % slides.length;
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = '';
}

function rightBtn() {
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = 'none';
   currentSlide = (--currentSlide + slides.length) % slides.length;
   slides[currentSlide].style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<ul id="slider_ul">
<li>First</li>
<li style="display:none">Second</li>
<li style="display:none">Third</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" onclick="rightBtn()">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="leftBtn()">Next</button>
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает.

Comment: @Malyuga Работает. Вы неправильно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но слайдер по прежнему не работает. Кнопки просто нажимаются

Comment: @Malyuga Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" во втором фрагменте. Вам понятно, что происходит?

Comment: Выполнил, да я понимаю логику этого

Comment: Спасибо, код работает. Дело было в том, что я использовал <a> вместо <button>

Comment: @Malyuga В таком случае Вам нужен: `onclick="leftBtn(); return false;"`